# Spring cloud data flow - File as input with Cloud Foundry Deployment

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have few applications in Spring XD and now I want to use Spring cloud dataflow deployed on Cloud Foundry. 
My input source is file. In Spring XD, I used to place the files in the local file system and XD streams used to read from that location. But with CF deployment, how can I specify the location of the remote file system? Will this file module work directly in CF?

Comment: You're likely going to be better off using a source like s3 or sftp, where the file will be reliably accessible in a cloud environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` source builds upon `java.io.File` spec and it is an object that is expected to exist in the local file system, so it wouldn't work on the cloud environment. There is however the "*persisted filesystem*" feature that is currently being developed in Cloud Foundry; once we have that feature, there'd be an option to wire the `file` source application with persistent mount.

With that said, as Corby pointed out in the comment, the best approach for cloud environments is to either use the [`s3`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/aws-s3/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-s3) or [`sftp`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/sftp/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-sftp) source applications.